# Using Rmagick with an uploaded file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick

`image.format` and `image.filename` work perfectly when the image has been read from a file that exists on disk. However, when reading an uploaded file that exists in memory (I think I'm using that term correctly), I can't really use rmagick at all:

```
ap data['file'] #=> #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000071f5d90 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140331-42056-w8cqh6>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2014-03-05 17:27:04.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[profile_image_attributes][file]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2014-03-05 17:27:04.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">

image = Magick::Image::from_blob(data['file'].read) # this doesn't give an error

image.format # private method `format' called for [ PNG 988x766 988x766+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 194kb]:Array ( works fine when image has been read from disk )
image.filename # undefined method, works fine when image has been read from disk
```

Does

```
private method `format' called for [ PNG 988x766 988x766+0+0 DirectClass 8-bit 194kb]:Array
```

give any clues?

Comment: I've been so long trying to do this. Don't know how this question can be clearer and more open ended.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation for [from_blob](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob) it looks like the return value is an array. So you might have to call **image[0].format** and **image[0].filename** instead of **image.format** and **image.filename**

Answer (score 2):

```
image = Magick::Image::from_blob(data['file'].read).first
```